# How to send json object to Rabbitmq server

Tags: json, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I am using spring3 and spring-amqp for sending the messages from my web application to `rabbitmq` server.

Currently I am able to send the plain text to rabbitmq server. But now I want to send my custom java object as json to the server.

After googling I just found we can do it using `JsonMessageConverter` . But I didn't get any useful url for explaining the required steps.

Any reference/url will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e367) (including how to use the `JsonMessageConverter`s.

And if you are using the namespace to define the template, it's

```
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
           message-converter="aJsonMCBean"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). See [this tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for example. Other alternatives:

- [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)
- [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)